# Erro ao ler uma string com scanf

Tags: c

A lógica eu já achei, mas estou tendo dificuldade para ler a string do jeito que a questão pede. Só aceita um número quando eu aperto enter, se não ele considera o número uma string.

Link para a questão:  https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/pt/problems/view/2650.

Eis o meu código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  int numero, alturam, i;
  scanf("%d %d", &numero, &alturam);
  int vet[numero];
  char nome[numero][100];
  for( i = 0; i < numero ; i++)
  {
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%[^\n] %d", nome[i], &vet[i]);
  }
  for( i = 0; i < numero ; i++)
  {
    if(vet[i] > alturam)
    {
        printf("%s\n", nome[i]);
    }
  }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Repare no final você armazena em %s, uma variável int

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vamos começar com isso:

```
scanf("%d %d", &numero, &alturam);
```

Isso daí vai consumir os dois números no início, mas não a quebra-de-linha que se segue. A solução é fazer isso:

```
scanf("%d %d\n", &numero, &alturam);
```

Agora, vamos ver essas duas linhas:

```
fflush(stdin);
scanf("%[^\n] %d", nome[i], &vet[i]);
```

O `fflush(stdin);` vai **destruir** qualquer entrada remanescente no programa. Se você fizer isso, o seu programa não conseguirá usar a entrada padrão dada pelo desafio para mais nada e qualquer `scanf` subsequente vai falhar. **Não use isso.** Lembre-se que nesse desafio (na verdade em todos os desafios da URI), a entrada é dada toda de uma vez só logo no início da execução no `stdin`, e os dados existentes no `stdin` só podem ser lidos uma única vez porque não tem como rebobinar ou voltar o `stdin`.

Já o `scanf("%[^\n] %d", nome[i], &vet[i]);` tem um problema: O `%[^\n]` vai consumir tudo até a quebra de linha, inclusive o número a ser lido. Quando o `%d` for tentado, não vai haver nenhum número disponível porque o `%[^\n]` já vai ter comido ele. E novamente, a quebra-de-linha vai continuar lá sem ser consumida também.

Assim, você vai precisar de algo mais esperto para separar o número do nome:

```
scanf("%[^\n]\n", nome[i]);
char *final_do_nome = strrchr(nome[i], ' ');
sscanf(final_do_nome, " %d", &vet[i]);
final_do_nome[0] = '\0';
```

Desta forma, o código completo fica assim:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  int numero, alturam, i;
  scanf("%d %d\n", &numero, &alturam);
  int vet[numero];
  char nome[numero][100];
  for (i = 0; i < numero; i++) {
    scanf("%[^\n]\n", nome[i]);
    char *final_do_nome = strrchr(nome[i], ' ');
    sscanf(final_do_nome, " %d", &vet[i]);
    final_do_nome[0] = '\0';
  }
  for (i = 0; i < numero; i++) {
    if (vet[i] > alturam) {
      printf("%s\n", nome[i]);
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Para esse código, quando é dada essa entrada:

```
3 50
Titan Colossal 60
Titan Encoracado 15
Titan Femea 14
```

É gerada essa saída:

```
Titan Colossal
```

Como tira-teima, vamos tentar essa outra entrada:

```
8 50
Titan Colossal 60
Titan Encoracado 15
Titan Femea 14
Titan Supremo 90
Titan quase grande o suficiente 50
Titan grande o suficiente para passar por cima 51
Titanzao 70
Titanzinho 13
```

Produz esta saída:

```
Titan Colossal
Titan Supremo
Titan grande o suficiente para passar por cima
Titanzao
```

[**Veja aqui funcionando no ideone.**](https://ideone.com/wbIo4m)

Comment: muito obrigado.

Comment: @rafaelmarques Se esta resposta resolveu o seu problema, marque-a como aceita ao clicar no "✅" que está ao lado dela. Isso também marcará a sua pergunta como solucionada/resolvida. Caso ainda não esteja satisfeito e lhe restem dúvidas ou objeções, sinta-se livre para comentar.